# Why Tomcat leaves lots of CLOSE_WAIT connections?

Tags: java, tomcat, tcp

I have a web application running on Tomcat 6.0.44 and after running during some time it leaves lots of CLOSE_WAIT connections.
After checking networks dumps I've found that connection close initiated from the server works fine with Normal Close Sequence according to the [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) (four-way close if I'm not mistaken).
But when the connection close is initiated by the client (Chrome browser) connection close sequence is not finished. And it seems to be the reason for CLOSE_WAIT connections.
Here is a [network dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmaYc.png) for one of the connections that are not properly closed. The client made POST to the server and then asked to close the connection before the server sent a response. The server sent ACK and sent a response with a redirect. Here the connection in a half-closed state if I understand it right. And the specification says that the server, in that case, can still send data but the client can't respond. And the server should've sent FIN ACK after sending the data.
So the question is why the client (browser) closed the connection before the server sent FIN ACK?

Comment: Tomcat 6? Yikes. That reached EOL nearly 2 years ago, and your specific version was released 2015-05-08, more than 4 years ago. There are published vulnerabilities for your version of Tomcat.

Comment: Practically speaking, clients can disappear at any time without cleanly closing their connections, so the server needs to be able to handle that. Tomcat and/or your OS's TCP/IP stack generally take care of that. How long are your CLOSE_WAIT connections remaining in that state?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I know, but we have to work with this old Tomcat. CLOSE_WAIT connections remain there for hours

Comment: Usually the OS can be tweaked to reduce that timeout so that the TCP/IP stack will drop connections with a shorter CLOSE_WAIT timeout. This isn't something you can adjust through Tomcat or the JVM.